# Grails publish-plugin to Grails Central successful but does not update latest version

Tags: grails, plugins, publish, codenarc

I successfully published the Grails **CodeNarc** Plugin version 0.23 to Grails Central, but the plugin page still shows 0.22 as the latest version. Ideas?

```
>grails publish-plugin
| Plugin packaged grails-codenarc-0.23.zip
| Plugin packaged grails-codenarc-0.23.zip
| POM generated:
C:\Users\Chris\Projects\GrailsCodeNarcPlugin\GrailsCodeNarc\target/pom.xml
WARN: No SCM provider installed.
Publishing to Grails Central
Publishing to http://grails.org/api/v1.0/publish/codenarc/0.23
Plugin successfully published.
Notifying plugin portal 'http://grails.org/plugin/codenarc' of release...
Notification successful
```

Thanks.
Chris

Comment: Someone mentioned this in the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grails-dev-discuss) - this has happened before but might be related to the recent site update. It'd be best to report this there so when someone can look at the server logs (I have no access) hopefully it'll be a quick fix.

Comment: This has been fixed now -- not sure how, but thanks.